# Polynomials with complex coefficients.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification, maximum-principle

Let $p(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$, where $a_0,a_1,..a_{n-1}$ are complex numbers and $q(z)=1+a_{n-1}z+..+a_0z^n$. If $|p(z)|\le 1$ for all with $|z|\le 1$, Then

$(1) \space |q(z)| \le 1$ for all z with $|z|\le 1$

$(2) \space q(z)$ is a constant polynomial

$(3)\space p(z)=z^n$ for all complex numbers $z$

$(4)\space p(z)$ is a constant polynomial

The way I tried :-

We have $q(z)=z^np\big(\frac1z\big)$

On $|z|=1$ we have $z=e^{i\theta}, 0\le \theta \le 2\pi$.

By Maximum Modulus Theorem,

$\displaystyle\max_{|z|\le 1}|q(z)|=\max_{|z|=1}|q(z)|=\max_{0\le \theta \le 2\pi}|e^{in\theta}p(e^{-i\theta})|\le 1$

But $q(0)=1$ . So by Maximum Modulus Theorem , we have  $q(z)=1$ i.e $a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}=...=a_0=0$

Hence $p(z)=z^n$. So correct options $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$

Is my work correct? Are there yet better approaches?

Thanks for your valuable time!!

Comment: what about options $1$?

Comment: Oh sorry ..that's obvious.